# Ideal way to model elements on a web page as classes in WebDriver for abstraction and re-use

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, abstraction, pageobjects

What could be the ideal way to model the elements on a webpage as classes for the sake of abstraction and re-usability?
Currently, what I have created is a BaseElement.java class that contains the following member variables:

```
WebDriver webdriver;
```

The constructor:

```
protected BaseElement(WebDriver driver)
 {
  //Initialization.
 }
```

I am then extending this class in other classes which represent a certain element on the webpage. 
For example, I have a Button.java class which extends BaseElement.java.

```
  public class ButtonElement extends BaseElement {


        String locator;
        By by;
        WebElement button;

        protected ButtonElement(WebDriver driver, String locator, By by) {
            super(driver);
            this.by = by;
            this.locator = locator;

           //code to find the element using driver.findElement()
           // I am not sure how to use By in here depending upon what I pass in the constructor when I create an object of this class. Any suggestions?
        }

        public void click() {

          button.click();
        }

        //Other methods which will interact with the element in other ways.
  }
```

So, in my PageObject classes, I will make use of the above like:

```
Button loginButton = new Button(driver,"btn-Login",By.id);
loginButton.click();
```

Is this the right approach? Is there any better way to abstract, hide complicated logic in a single class, and reuse the elements like button, textbox, select list etc from a webdriver perspective?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe passing in the driver each time you locate an element is the way to go, but I understand you are aiming to avoid repeating code. You could instead have a class that accesses a driver class, which is instantiated at the start of your code. This way you can pass in a 'type' and 'attribute' which will locate any implemented element. eg. Type: Id, Class, XPath; and Attribute: "text", "//div[@class="class"]/div[2]".

So,

**DriverClass**: Has a WebDriver that implements FindElement with a switch for each type.

**WrapperClass**: Which has classes such as 'Click' or 'DoesElementExist' which uses DriverClass to implement functionality.

**TestClass**: Using calls to WrapperClass implements your code logic.

You could go further and implement common groupings of actions in another class that utilises WrapperClass so TestClass becomes a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this case, there is more than one correct way to do it.

1st **do not reinvent the wheel** - there exists PageObject which does probably the same as you want: [Read about it here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

2nd my personal approach is to have Class for every page I visit and model methods to describe what they are doing. Something like this:

```
 class InitPage {
   private Webdriver driver;

   public InitPage(){
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://my-test-page.com");
   }

    public WebDriver getDriver(){
     return driver;
    }

    public AdminPage loginToSite(String username, String Password){#
     WebElement login = driver.FindElement(By.id("adm-login");
     login.sendKeys(username);
     WebElement pwd = driver.FindElement(By.id("adm-pwd");
     pwd.sendKeys(password);
     WebElement confirmButton = driver.FindElement(By.id("login-submit");\
     confirmButton.click();
     return new AdminPage(this);

   }

 }


class AdminPage{
  private InitPage initPage

  public AdminPage(InitPage init){
     this.initPage = init;
  }

  public String getLoggedInUser();
  WebElement user = initPage.getDriver().findElement(By.id("usr-credential-name")); //just show off how you approach the webDriver
  return user.getText();   

}
```

And later on in the tests:

```
@Test
public void TestLoging(){
  InitPage firstPage = new InitPage();
  AdminPage administration = firstPage.login("Pavel", "omgTooSecretToTellYou!");
  Assert.assertEquals(administration.getLoggedInUser(), "Pavel"); //example how you can do the tests
}
```

Comment: I don't think you really got my problem and your answer is not even near the context of my question. I know what PageObjects are and I have used the PageObject pattern in the automation framework I'm developing. My question is only about abstracting out the elements (as in, the controls like Buttons, Textboxes, Dropdown lists) on a webpage so that I can isolate out all the code interacting with that control in a separate class. My pageobject classes contain code exactly specified by you. What if I want to further go ahead and include another level of abstraction for the mentioned elements?

Comment: Well, personally I do not see any value added between WebElement and "Button" where both have "click" and "getText" - in way you are only renaming WebElement class to have "nicer" name. And as stated in the question "what is the idal way to..." does not have only one correct answer. What I answered you is my solution to the problem you are having. Maybe not the best one, but best for me ;)

Comment: Please don't consider only the given example. I don't intend to simply cover webelement's functions within another class for a "nice" name. There are other scenarios where I want to perform a series of operations on a webelement which represent a single operation. Ok, so can you modify your solution to my requirement where the context is only a control (textbox, radiobutton, drop-down) and not a page/ a section of it? By design, you can't consider a control as a PageObject, can you?

Comment: For example, consider a table or auto-complete search field.

Answer (score 1):

I partly agree with Abhijeet and Pavel , When Abstracting a Webelement it would be good for you to Extend a Class which has already implemented all the Methods of Webelements interface , Other wise as Pavel said it would be like reinventing the Wheel , My personal opinion would be to Abstract larger WebElements like Forms which inturn has multiple Webelements  ie eg. Forms are like Smaller pages ...But again that  is my Personal Opinion.